# How to implement a k-way merge sort?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I need to implement a function which does a k-way merge sort on an unsorted array or integers.

The function takes in two parameters, an integer K, which is the "way" of the sort and always a power of 2. The second parameter is the array of integers to be sorted, whose length is also a power of 2.

The function is to return an array containing the sorted elements. So far, I know how to implement a regular merge sort. How would I modify this code so that it implements a K-way merge sort? (Note: this function doesn't return the sorted array, I need help with that as well. It also doesn't take in K, since its a regular merge sort)

Below code:

```
public class MergeSort {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  }

  public static void mergeSort(int[] inputArray) {
    int size = inputArray.length;
    if (size < 2)
        return;
    int mid = size / 2;
    int leftSize = mid;
    int rightSize = size - mid;
    int[] left = new int[leftSize];
    int[] right = new int[rightSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
        left[i] = inputArray[i];

    }
    for (int i = mid; i < size; i++) {
        right[i - mid] = inputArray[i];
    }
    mergeSort(left);
    mergeSort(right);
    merge(left, right, inputArray);
  }

  public static void merge(int[] left, int[] right, int[] arr) {
    int leftSize = left.length;
    int rightSize = right.length;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < leftSize && j < rightSize) {
      if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
        arr[k] = left[i];
        i++;
        k++;
      } else {
        arr[k] = right[j];
        k++;
        j++;
      }
    }
    while (i < leftSize) {
      arr[k] = left[i];
      k++;
      i++;
    }
    while (j < leftSize) {
      arr[k] = right[j];
      k++;
      j++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you consider a "k-way merge sort"? The question you're asking doesn't really make a lot of sense because there's no particular advantage to modifying merge sort to make it use a k-way merge. The 2-way merge is already optimum for this algorithm.

Comment: @Jim Mischel Perhaps - preparing to external sorting studying.

Comment: @MBo: but that's something entirely different that has at best a casual relationship to merge sort. You don't modify merge sort to create an external sort. Regardless, his question is not at all clear.

Comment: @MBo Sorry if I wasn't clear. Let me outline the steps I need to take. The elements of the input array are distributed amongst K other arrays of size n/K. Then I need to recursively call my kwaymergesort function on each of the K arrays, and keep track of the returned arrays. Then I need to merge these arrays into a single array of size n, which is sorted.

Comment: @Mr. Pickles Are you familiar with usual merge sort? I did not check your code but `merge` function looks right

Comment: @Jim Mischel I think I understand how once I have the K sorted arrays I can merge them into a single sorted array. i just don't understand why recursively calling my kwaymergesort function will result in me having the K sorted arrays to merge. Also, what would the exit condition for my recursion look like?

Comment: @MBo I understand how the regular merge sort works. I believe that merge function is correct. I just don't understand how to change this to make it into a k-way merge sort. If I were to recursively call the kwaymergesort function on each of my k sub-arrays, and have K pointers in my merge function, would this achieve the sort? I just don't understand the recursive step.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is this: http://bchalk.com/work/view/k_way_merge_sort

Comment: @Mr. Pickles I added recursion flow description to my answer. Hope it would  help.

Comment: @JimMischel - "no particular advantage ... k-way merge". In some cases a 4 way merge is faster than 2 way, if there are 16 or so registers (most of them used as pointers) such as X86 in 64 bit mode. The total number of operations is the same, but the change is 1.5 x number of compares and 0.5 x number of moves. This ends up a bit more cache friendly and in the case of sorting integers, about a 15% increase in speed.

Answer (score 2):

Regular merge sort is two-way sorting. You compare elements from the first and the second halves of array and copy smallest to output array.

For k-way sorting you divide input array into K parts. K indexes point to the first elements of every part. To effectively choose the smallest of them, use priority queue (based on binary heap) and pop the smallest element from the heap top at every step. When you pop element belonging to the m-th part, push the next element from the same part (if it still exists)

Let you have array length 16 and k = 4.
The first recursion level calls  4 mergesorts for arrays copied from indexes 0..3, 4..7, 8..11, 12..15.
The second recursion level gets length 4 array and calls 4 mergesorts for 1-element arrays.
The third recursion level gets length 1 array and immediately returns (such array is sorted).
Now at the second recursion level you merge 4 one-element arrays into one sorted array.
Now at the first recursion level you merge 4 four-element arrays into one sorted array length 16

Comment: A generic k-way merge sort is simpler if implemented as a [bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation) . Assuming an reasonably optimized merge sort using indices, top down has to push and pop generated indices to / from the stack during recursion, while bottom up skips all of that recursion and uses iteration to advance the k indices during each k-way merge pass.